# QC Report: Which test cases have not been linked to at least one test set?

Tags: manual-testing, quality-center

I am still pretty new here, but couldn't find an answer so far.

I want to know if there are any test cases (if possible of a specific folder in the Test Plan) that have not been linked to a test set, and therefore won't be tested.

We are still at the beginning... and I want to show the testers a list of test cases that they might have forgotten about.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks and stay safe.

Regina

Answer (score 1):

if you use Quality Center 10, you can use the Excel report in the Dashboard to get your information. The following query will give you the count of test instance in the TestLab. Thus 0 means the test case in TestPlan is not linked to any test instance/TestSet in TestLab.

```
SELECT 
  tb1.ts_name as "TestCase Name" 
, count(tb3.cy_cycle) as "CountInstance" 
FROM TEST tb1
,TESTCYCL tb2 
,CYCLE tb3
where tb1.ts_test_id = tb2.tc_test_id(+) 
and tb2.tc_cycle_id = tb3.cy_cycle_id(+)
group by ts_name
```

Basically, you have to link tables Test (TestPlan), TestCycl (TestInstance) and Cycle (TestSet). You cannot link TestPlan directly to TestSet.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The link below has the ER diagram of TEST, TESTCYCL, and CYCLE tables. Also an example to retrieve the status of the tests. That will give you the results of the test that have not run.

[QC Retrieving test status](http://qtp-automate.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/how-to-retrieve-test-sets-test.html)

Comment: What's testcycl?

Comment: TestCycl is the table in QC database that has records stored for test instanace with in a test set